# How to use HelloGallery Widget

Tags: android

I am running the [HelloGallery example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) for Android (using the XML layout file below), and I am now wondering how I would use it in my app.

It is referred to as a "layout widget". Is this different than an "app widget"?
I am having trouble finding resources for adding this to my app, since when I search for "layout widget" I get references to widgets that float around on the home screen, and not using them within apps.

How would this be done?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A layout widget would be some custom view that is part of your layout for an activity in an application. An App widget is exactly what you stated, as "widgets that float around on the home screen". They are an external interface to your application, and here's a tutorial link for you on them. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: Thanks, but the link shows how to use app widgets... how do you use layout widgets?

Comment: when you make a custom view you can include it into your layout.xml file with the full extension name say the package hierarchy - com.hello.customWidgetThing. This object is then in the com.hello package called customWidgetThing and extends View or ViewHolder. Once youve created the widget and have an instance in your viewHolders xml file, you can then inflate it as usual with the type customWidgetThing.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it working with your help, and also found the documentation on the subject: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html